# Keep prompting the the user until valid value provided-while loop c programming

Tags: c

I am learning c programming beginner.At while loop stage i am trying validating user input using while loop program working just fine according to my expectation except one thing which is whenever user input invalid value loop terminate itself and i am trying to keep asking the user until the valid value taken from user.Here is the code i am working on it.Can anyone guide me through this?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int num;
    int sum;
    bool flag = 0;

    printf("Enter the value GREATER than 20 and LESS than 25: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);

    while ( num > 20 && num < 25 ) {
        sum += num;
        num++;
    }
    if ( num < 20 || num > 25){
        flag = 0;
        printf("Invalid\n");
    }
    else
        printf("sum of your number is : %d \n", sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to move `scanf` inside a loop.

Comment: @FiddlingBits It's a start, but then `num` is used for comparison while uninitialized.  Gotta make it a `do-while-loop`.

Comment: Also, `sum +=num` is a problem since `sum` is uninitialized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need scanf inside while loop to get the correct value from user by asking continuesly. Once you get correct value you don't need if condition to check correctness of value because while loop exits only after getting correct value.

```
#include <stdio.h>

    int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
    {
    int num = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    bool flag = 0;

    printf("Enter the value GREATER than 20 and LESS than 25: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);

    while ( num < 20 || num >25 )
    {
    printf("Invalid number,Enter the value GREATER than 20 and LESS than 25: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    }

while (  num <= 25 )
     { 
         sum += num;
          num++; 
    }


        printf("sum of your number is : %d \n", sum);
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: it's not giving the sum of number.

Comment: What it's giving?

Comment: nothing just 0 if i add sum+= in the loop and outside the loop it echo the number.

Comment: `scanf` can't be used for this. Try the input `11 abc 24` Use `fgets` and `sscanf`

Comment: Do you want to add the number continuesly if the number is >20 and <25.

Comment: I want the sum of the value between 20 to 25